# Mysql query to find top posted users

Tags: mysql

i have two tables called `posts` and `posts_comments` with the structure as follows.

posts table

```
id username post
1   soju     hi
2   alan     hello
3   soju     hola
4   sam      good morning
```

posts_comments table

```
id  post_id posted_username  comment
 1    1       jerin             hello
 2    1       jerin             hi
 3    1       catty             good morning
 4    4       catty             hi
 5    3       catty             hello
```

where post_id refers to post tables id.what i want is to find top 3 most posted users included from both post and comments table using a single query so the output would be

```
username  number of post
catty       3
jerin       2
soju        2
```

so far i have 2 separate query and use server side script to find top 3

```
select username,count(*) as number of post group by username from posts

select posted_username as username 
from posts_comments group by posted_username 
from posts_comments
```

how can i write this as a single query?

Comment: I am pretty sure that Neither of those Queries are syntactically correct

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION` to combine the two queries. Then you can add the two counts together to get the number of posts and comments, and get the top 3 of that total.

```
SELECT username, SUM(number_of_posts) AS number_of_posts
FROM (
    SELECT username, COUNT(*) AS number_of_posts
    FROM posts
    GROUP BY username
    UNION ALL
    SELECT posted_username AS username, COUNT(*) AS number_of_posts
    FROM posts_comments
    GROUP BY posted_username
) AS combined
ORDER BY number_of_posts DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Make sure you use `UNION ALL`. By default `UNION` removes duplicates, so if a user has the same number of posts and comments they will not both be counted.

Also you need to review the syntax of `SELECT` queries -- the order of clauses is not flexible as you've written them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.both post and post_comments are really big tables with lots of records in it. i am worried about union

Comment: The union doesn't happen until after grouping, so it's not as big as combining the entire tables.

Comment: your answer looks good. can we use join query to achive this?

Comment: You would need an `OUTER JOIN`, since there may be some users who post but don't comment, and other users who comment but don't post. But MySQL doesn't have `OUTER JOIN`. The workaround to this is to use a `UNION`, so it's not really much of an improvement.

Comment: because later it needs to be paginated as well

Comment: can this possible with left join? i try for around an hour and give up

Comment: No matter what you do, it has to combine the data from the two tables.

Comment: Left join will work for users in the left table that aren't in the right table, but won't find users in the right table that aren't in the left table. That's why outer join is needed.

Comment: reverse case will not happen.because  post have comments.no comments exist in my case without having posts

Comment: That's not the issue. You're counting by user, so you would have to join the tables on the username, not the post ID.

Comment: Never mind, you're counting by the name of the original poster, not the commenter.

Comment: I take that back again. `posted_username` is the name of the commenter, not the name of the original poster, since that's in the `posts` table. You can't do what you want with LEFT JOIN.

Comment: hmm i think so. does the outer select helps to prevent the query from timeout issues?.sorry for asking this. i am little bit weak in mysql stuff

Comment: The outer select is needed to combine the post + comment counts from the two inner queries.

Comment: If someone posts 3 times and comments 10 times, their count should be 13, right?

Answer (score 0):

A poster may also post comments so you need to combine counts. Here a full join is emulated. **I have also added one additional comment by user alan for testing purposes.** But I should not have had to create the db-fiddle (this is the OP's responsibility).

[See Db Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fnPHFwLaJ9411mRBx38mDi/2)

```
 SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT t1.username, t1.cnt + ifnull(t2.cnt, 0) cnt from (
      SELECT username, count(*) cnt FROM posts group by username
    ) t1
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT posted_username, count(*) cnt from post_comments group by posted_username
    ) t2
    ON t1.username = t2.posted_username
  UNION
    SELECT t2.posted_username, t2.cnt + ifnull(t1.cnt, 0) cnt from (
      SELECT username, count(*) cnt FROM posts group by username
    ) t1
    RIGHT JOIN (
      SELECT posted_username, count(*) cnt from post_comments group by posted_username
    ) t2
    ON t1.username = t2.posted_username
 ) sq ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 3


| username | cnt |
| -------- | --- |
| catty    | 3   |
| alan     | 2   |
| soju     | 2   |
```